# How should I use DB4O in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, db4o

I'm interested in using DB4O in asp.net mvc applications. However I can't find any good samples that show how to set things up. For example, do I have to create a custom IHttpModule that manages the lifetime of a DB4O server instance?
Any pointers to useful articles and sample code would be excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this forum post](http://developer.db4o.com/Forums/tabid/98/afv/topic/aff/4/aft/1040/afpg/1/Default.aspx) from the db4o website, it shows a few good alternatives.  In the past I have used a custom HttpModule similar to the one ~7 posts down and it worked well for me.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've updated the code given there to work with the latest Db4o API. It seems there have been a few changes since that post.

Comment: any chance of seeing the updated code?  Am having problems with the connection being closed.

Answer (score 1):

More info:

http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-7.12/net35/reference/html/reference/platform_specific_issues/asp.net.html